# Make user check all answers on form

Tags: php, forms

Is there a way to modify my database-powered quiz so that, if a user doesn't answer one or more questions, clicking the Submit button will trigger an alert? In other words, I want to force users to answer all the questions, even if they just guess. The scoring mechanism doesn't work correctly unless all the questions have a response.

Note that some questions (the last one in this example) may have multiple correct answers. I think all that matters is that at least one checkbox is selected.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="quiz">

  <li id="q9">
    <div class="Question">Scientists believe the universe is:</div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-A"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-A" value="A" style="display: none;"> A. disappearing</div></label></div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-B"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-B" value="B" style="display: none;"> B. expanding</div></label></div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-C"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-C" value="C" style="display: none;"> C. contracting</div></label></div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-D"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-D" value="D" style="display: none;"> D. becoming bipolar</div></label></div>
  </li>
  <li id="q10">
    <div class="Question">Check each item that can be found in our solar system.</div>
    <div class="Answer" style="margin-top: 5px; background: #000; color: #fff; text-align: center;">
    <label for="q10-A"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-A" value="A">planet</label>
       <label for="q10-B"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-B" value="B">asteroid</label>
       <label for="q10-C"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-C" value="C">comet</label>
       <label for="q10-D"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-D" value="D">black hole</label>
       <label for="q10-E"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-E" value="E">neutrino star</label>
       <label for="q10-F"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-F" value="F">quasar</label>
     </div>
      </li>
 </ol>
 <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" id="url" />
 <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="54f3f5438292e" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the complete solution to your question as below:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="quiz" onsubmit="return formValidate();">

  <li id="q9">
    <div class="Question">Scientists believe the universe is:</div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-A"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-A" value="A"> A. disappearing</div></label></div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-B"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-B" value="B"> B. expanding</div></label></div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-C"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-C" value="C"> C. contracting</div></label></div>
    <div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q9-D"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q9[]" id="q9-D" value="D"> D. becoming bipolar</div></label></div>
  </li>
  <li id="q10">
    <div class="Question">Check each item that can be found in our solar system.</div>
    <div class="Answer" style="margin-top: 5px; background: #000; color: #fff; text-align: center;">
    <label for="q10-A"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-A" value="A">planet</label>
       <label for="q10-B"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-B" value="B">asteroid</label>
       <label for="q10-C"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-C" value="C">comet</label>
       <label for="q10-D"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-D" value="D">black hole</label>
       <label for="q10-E"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-E" value="E">neutrino star</label>
       <label for="q10-F"><input type="checkbox" name="q10[]" id="q10-F" value="F">quasar</label>
     </div>
      </li>
 </ol>
 <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" id="url" />
 <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="54f3f5438292e" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidate(){
    var qno = 2; // Total Questions, say. in your example it's 2 (9 and 10)
    var i = 9; // Question No to start with, say. in your example it's 9
    var qcount = (i+qno)-1;
    for(i; i <= qcount; i++){
        qid = 'q'+i+'[]';
        var qidElement = document.getElementsByName(qid);
        var checkcount = 0;
            for(var j=0; j < qidElement.length; ++j){
                if(qidElement[j].checked){
                    ++checkcount;
                }
            }
            if(checkcount == 0){
                alert("Please select at least one Answer for Question no. "+i);
                return false;
            }
    }
    document.getElementById('quiz').submit();
}
</script>
```

Input values for `qno` & `i` in javascript function as per your requirement, as guided by me in the relevant comments beside them.

Let me know if there is any issue. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to force users to fill all fields you have to use one off those validation methods :

1- Client side: via java script , but user can bypass it by disable java script "not recommended".

2- Server side: user can't disable it , and the code related to your programming language .

3- Mix type: Via Ajax and that is the best choice

Example

A-Check request in server side and return results in JSON type .

B-Process returned data via JavaScript and display results in the form

Check this links will help you so much:

http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp